# None как логическая переменная в Python

Tags: python

Можно ли использовать None в Python, как значение логической переменной на равне с True и False ?

Comment: вот только ` print(bool(b))
False`

Comment: @KoVadim а b это ?

Comment: хотел написать так `print(bool(None))` будет `False`

Comment: Вопрос таки непонятен. Может код (псевдокод) какой приведёте - что имелось в виду?

Comment: @CrazyElf имелась в виду троичная логика

Comment: да, автору вопроса хотелось использовать True/False/None как троичную логику. Но не факт, что это получится. Используйте свой энум/константы

Comment: Ну теоретически можно. Хотя лучше специальный класс для этого написать со специальными встроенными в него значениями.